# How to create MaskTransformation using Picasso? Both images from server side mask image and other image

Tags: android

I want mask image and other image getting from server

```
  Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                    .load("http://s1.picswalls.com/wallpapers/2014/07/24/awesome-pattern-wallpaper_113041209_88.jpg")
                    .transform(new MaskTransformation(MainActivity.this,"http://s1.picswalls.com/wallpapers/2014/07/24/maskImage.jpg"))
                    .into(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

after lots of try.I got answer for this problem
please change class MaskTransformation like below

```
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.Canvas;
    import android.graphics.Paint;
    import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
    import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
    import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

    import com.squareup.picasso.Transformation;

    public class MaskTransformation implements Transformation {

        private static Paint mMaskingPaint = new Paint();

        static {
            mMaskingPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
        }

        private Drawable maskId;

        /**
         * @param maskId If you change the mask file, please also rename the mask file, or Glide will get
         *               the cache with the old mask. Because getId() return the same values if using the
         *               same make file name. If you have a good idea please tell us, thanks.
         */
        public MaskTransformation(Drawable maskId) {
            this.maskId = maskId;
        }

        @Override
        public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {
            int width = source.getWidth();
            int height = source.getHeight();

            Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

            Drawable mask = this.maskId;

            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
            mask.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);
            mask.draw(canvas);
            canvas.drawBitmap(source, 0, 0, mMaskingPaint);

            source.recycle();

            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public String key() {
            return "MaskTransformation(maskId=" + maskId
                    + ")";
        }
    }
```

> In activity write below code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView imageView;
    Button btnMask;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                .load("http://pixlab.xyz/images/eye_mask.png")
                .into(imageView);


        btnMask = findViewById(R.id.btnMask);
        btnMask.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
//                  if you want to get bitmap and drawable from imageview
//                 Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
//                Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
                Drawable drawable=imageView.getDrawable();
                MaskTransformation maskTransformation = new MaskTransformation(drawable);
                Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                        .load("http://s1.picswalls.com/wallpapers/2014/07/24/awesome-pattern-wallpaper_113041209_88.jpg")
                        .transform(maskTransformation)
                        .into(imageView);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

> MainActivity layout xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="MainActivity">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnMask"
        android:text="submit"
        />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

> Note : Loading image from server take some time that why when you try before complete download image then exception occur